pyqtgraph raises error anytime i move cursor above it
I want to display my data by pyatgraph, mostly because of an easy FFT method it provides. I wrote an GUI by Qt Designer and created pyqtgraph in it. The problem occurs when I try to plot my data. The graph does not appear, and the following error constantly pops up whenever I move the cursor above the plot:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\22960\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotCurveItem.py", line 299, in boundingRect
    (xmn, xmx) = self.dataBounds(ax=0)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\22960\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\PlotCurveItem.py", line 249, in dataBounds
    b = ( float(np.nanmin(d)), float(np.nanmax(d)) ) # enforce float format for bounds, even if data format is different
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\22960\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\nanfunctions.py", line 343, in nanmin
    res = np.fmin.reduce(a, axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'fmin' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U8'), dtype('<U8')) -> None

Main code is:
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene,QMainWindow
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import typing
import threading as th
import interface  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
from scipy.signal import hilbert, find_peaks, butter, filtfilt, savgol_filter
from PyEMD import EMD
from datetime import datetime as dt

def find_max_scipy(x: np.ndarray, min_distance: int=None,
                   min_height=None, min_width=None) -> float:
    # validate
    if(not isinstance(x, np.ndarray)):
        return np.array([])
    if(not (isinstance(min_distance, float) or isinstance(min_distance, int) or
            isinstance(min_distance, type(None)))):
        return np.array([])
    if(not (isinstance(min_height, int) or isinstance(min_height, float) or 
            isinstance(min_height, type(None)))):
        return np.array([])
    if(not (isinstance(min_width, type(None)) or isinstance(min_width, float)
            or isinstance(min_width, int))):
        return np.array([])
    
    # preset
    if(isinstance(min_width, type(None))):
        min_width = len(x) / 20
    if(isinstance(min_distance, type(None))):
       min_distance = 10
    # if(isinstance(min_height, type(None))):
    #     min_height = abs(x.max() - x.min()) / 4
    
    # cases
    if(isinstance(min_height, type(None)) and isinstance(min_distance,
                                                         type(None))):
        return(find_peaks(x, width=min_width)[0])
    if(isinstance(min_height, type(None))):
        return(find_peaks(x, distance=min_distance, width=min_width)[0])
    if(isinstance(min_distance, type(None))):
        return(find_peaks(x, height=min_height, width=min_width)[0])
    
    return(find_peaks(x, height=min_height, distance=min_distance,
                      width=min_width)[0])

def lowpass_filtr(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, thereshold_freq=0.2):
    """
    Original low-pass filter.
    Parameters
    ----------
    
    thereshold_freq: float
        0.2 -> thereshold_T = 5 nm.
        1 -> thresehold_t = 1 nm.
    """
    
    Sample_rate = x.size / (x[-1] - x[0])
    
    # thereshold_freq
    slice_freq = 2*thereshold_freq/Sample_rate
    
    b, a = butter(N=2, Wn=slice_freq, btype='lowpass', analog=False, fs=1)
    y_clean = filtfilt(b, a, y)  
    
    return y_clean

def savitzky_golay(y, window_size=501, order=3, deriv=0, rate=1):
    r"""Smooth (and optionally differentiate) data with a Savitzky-Golay filter.
    The Savitzky-Golay filter removes high frequency noise from data.
    It has the advantage of preserving the original shape and
    features of the signal better than other types of filtering
    approaches, such as moving averages techniques.
    Parameters
    ----------
    y : array_like, shape (N,)
        the values of the time history of the signal.
    window_size : int
        the length of the window. Must be an odd integer number.
    order : int
        the order of the polynomial used in the filtering.
        Must be less then `window_size` - 1.
    deriv: int
        the order of the derivative to compute (default = 0 means only smoothing)
    Returns
    -------
    ys : ndarray, shape (N)
        the smoothed signal (or it's n-th derivative).
    Notes
    -----
    The Savitzky-Golay is a type of low-pass filter, particularly
    suited for smoothing noisy data. The main idea behind this
    approach is to make for each point a least-square fit with a
    polynomial of high order over a odd-sized window centered at
    the point.
    Examples
    --------
    t = np.linspace(-4, 4, 500)
    y = np.exp( -t**2 ) + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, t.shape)
    ysg = savitzky_golay(y, window_size=31, order=4)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(t, y, label='Noisy signal')
    plt.plot(t, np.exp(-t**2), 'k', lw=1.5, label='Original signal')
    plt.plot(t, ysg, 'r', label='Filtered signal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] A. Savitzky, M. J. E. Golay, Smoothing and Differentiation of
       Data by Simplified Least Squares Procedures. Analytical
       Chemistry, 1964, 36 (8), pp 1627-1639.
    .. [2] Numerical Recipes 3rd Edition: The Art of Scientific Computing
       W.H. Press, S.A. Teukolsky, W.T. Vetterling, B.P. Flannery
       Cambridge University Press ISBN-13: 9780521880688
    """
    
    from math import factorial
    
    try:
        window_size = np.abs(int(window_size))
        order = np.abs(int(order))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("window_size and order have to be of type int")
    if window_size % 2 != 1 or window_size < 1:
        raise TypeError("window_size size must be a positive odd number")
    if window_size < order + 2:
        raise TypeError("window_size is too small for the polynomials order")
    order_range = range(order+1)
    half_window = (window_size -1) // 2
    # precompute coefficients
    b = np.mat([[k**i for i in order_range] for k in range(-half_window, half_window+1)])
    m = np.linalg.pinv(b).A[deriv] * rate**deriv * factorial(deriv)
    # pad the signal at the extremes with
    # values taken from the signal itself
    firstvals = y[0] - np.abs(y[1:half_window+1][::-1] - y[0])
    lastvals = y[-1] + np.abs(y[-half_window-1:-1][::-1] - y[-1])
    y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals))
    return np.convolve( m[::-1], y, mode='valid')

def envelope_EMD(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, up_or_down: str="down"):
    if(up_or_down not in ("up", "down")):
        print("Incorrect argument in envelope")
        return (np.array([]), np.array([]))
    try:
        
        #Execute EMD on signal
        IMF = EMD(spline_kind="cubic")
        IMF.extrema_detection = "simple"
        
        all_extrema = IMF.find_extrema(x, y)
        
        if(up_or_down=="down"):
            x_minims, y_minims = all_extrema[2], all_extrema[3]
        
            extrem = np.array([x_minims, y_minims])
        
        else:
            x_maxims, y_maxims = all_extrema[0], all_extrema[1]
            extrem = np.array([x_maxims, y_maxims])
            
        env = IMF.spline_points(x, extrem)
        
        return env[0], env[1]
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return (np.array([]), np.array([]))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, interface.Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        self.save_base_data.clicked.connect(self.set_base_data)
        self.import_data.clicked.connect(self.Plot)
        
    def set_base_data(self):
        global input_n_ref
        global input_l_ref
        global input_l_sens
        input_n_ref = float(self.input_n_ref.text())
        input_l_ref = float(self.input_l_ref.text())
        input_l_sens = float(self.input_l_sens.text())
        print(input_n_ref ,input_l_ref ,input_l_sens)

    def Plot(self):
        # self.widget.clear()
        points=[]
        path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, r"C:\Users\22960\Desktop", "Выберите папку")
        points=defining(path)
        print(points)
        self.widget.plot(time,points)


def defining(path):
    files = [os.path.join(path,data_file) for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(path))]
    n1L=[]
    shift=[]
    global time
    time=[]
    for i in files:
        df= pd.read_csv(i, encoding='cp1251', sep=';')

        x = df.iloc[:,0]
        pd.to_numeric(x)
        x = x.tolist() 
        x = np.asarray(x)

        data = df.iloc[:,1]
        pd.to_numeric(data)
        data = data.tolist()
        data = np.asarray(data)
        data = lowpass_filtr(x, data)
        data = 10**(data/10) 


        y_fine=savitzky_golay(data)
        envelope_x, envelope_y = envelope_EMD(x, y_fine)
        envelope_y=savitzky_golay(envelope_y, window_size=801, order =3)
        peak_index = find_max_scipy(envelope_y)
        
        P0=envelope_x[peak_index[0]]
        P1=envelope_x[peak_index[1]]
        # print (P0, P1)
        omega = np.pi*(P0*P1)/(abs(P1-P0))
        L2= input_l_ref 
        L1= input_l_sens 
        n= input_n_ref 
        n1=((omega/(2*np.pi))+L1*1000*n)/(L2*1000) 
        answer = n1
        shift.append(P0)
        n1L.append(n1)
        fname= os.path.basename(i)
        derr = dt.strptime(fname, 'spectrum_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%f.csv')
        derr = derr.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        time.append(derr)
    
    
    return n1L


    
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()  
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()  

Basically, the working data is two columns of numbers in csv format.
My interface code is here:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1272, 641)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("#centralwidget {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(63, 129, 158);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 253, 253);\n"
"    border-radius: 5px;\n"
"    padding: 10px 10px;\n"
"    color: rgb(55, 107, 113);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    color: rgb(45, 97, 100);\n"
"    border: 1px  solid rgb(55, 107, 113);\n"
"    cursor: pointer;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit {\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    border-radius:5px;\n"
"    color: rgb(55, 107, 113);\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.n_ref = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.n_ref.setFont(font)
        self.n_ref.setObjectName("n_ref")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.n_ref)
        self.input_n_ref = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_n_ref.setObjectName("input_n_ref")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.input_n_ref)
        self.label_ref = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_ref.setObjectName("label_ref")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_ref)
        self.input_l_ref = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_l_ref.setObjectName("input_l_ref")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.input_l_ref)
        self.label_sens = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_sens.setObjectName("label_sens")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_sens)
        self.input_l_sens = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_l_sens.setObjectName("input_l_sens")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.input_l_sens)
        self.save_base_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.save_base_data.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.save_base_data.setCheckable(False)
        self.save_base_data.setObjectName("save_base_data")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.save_base_data)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.formLayout.setItem(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, spacerItem)
        self.import_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.import_data.setObjectName("import_data")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.import_data)
        self.label_results = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_results.setObjectName("label_results")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.label_results)
        self.label_n_sens = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_n_sens.setObjectName("label_n_sens")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_n_sens)
        self.lcd_n_sens = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd_n_sens.setObjectName("lcd_n_sens")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(7, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lcd_n_sens)
        self.label_c_sens = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_c_sens.setObjectName("label_c_sens")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_c_sens)
        self.lcd_c_sens = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd_c_sens.setObjectName("lcd_c_sens")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(8, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lcd_c_sens)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.formLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(20)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(20)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.n_ref.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">n</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt; vertical-align:sub;\"> сравнение</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_ref.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">L</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt; vertical-align:sub;\">сравнение</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_ref.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">L</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt; vertical-align:sub;\">сравнение</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">, </span><span style=\" font-size:18pt;\">мкм</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_sens.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">L</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt; vertical-align:sub;\">измерение</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">, </span><span style=\" font-size:18pt;\">мкм</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.save_base_data.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Записать данные"))
        self.import_data.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Импорт данных эксперимента"))
        self.label_results.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">Результаты измерений</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_n_sens.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">n</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt; vertical-align:sub;\">измерение</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_c_sens.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">C</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt; vertical-align:sub;\">измерение</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">, </span><span style=\" font-size:18pt;\">%</span><span style=\" font-size:18pt; vertical-align:sub;\">масс</span><span style=\" font-size:20pt;\">:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget


I really do not know how to solve the problem.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You might have non-numeric values in your CSV. Please be sure that your CSV is correctly formatted.
Another catch is to change your code from pd.to_numeric(x) to x = pd.to_numeric(x) in the defining function.
You also might want to drop None values by x = x.dropna()
Please update your question if these steps do not help.
